# Intersection of two lists in Python avoiding redundant matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two python lists `match1` and `match2`

`match1` = `['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'notcomplete' , 'next']`

`match2` = `['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'blocked', 'paper' , 'next']`

Now, I used  `__ contains __` to find the common words between `match1` and `match2`

`common = filter(set(match1).__contains__,match2)`

`print(list(common))`

This gave me the following output

`['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'paper' , 'next']`

The word `paper` in the second list matched again with the word `paper` in first list.

Is there a way to avoid this and get the following output ?

`['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'next']`

**Edit :**

The order of the list is important. This is why I used __ contains __ and not intersection.

My concern is not the presence of duplicate entries in the common words list. I am trying to avoid the same entry in `match1` being matched once again with another entry in `match2`. If both lists had two `'paper'`, I would take it in the common list as separate entries.

Comment: Use a set for both variables: `filter(set(match1).__contains__,set(match2))`

Comment: Do you want to have repeated items in the list or not

Comment: @programmerpro I would like to keep the order of the list and repeatation does not matter unless it is not by matching a word that was once already matched.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the list to set and then use the intersection function in set to find the common words.

```
match1 = ['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'notcomplete' , 'next']
match2 = ['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'blocked', 'paper' , 'next']
match1_set = set(match1)
match2_set = set(match2)
print(match1_set.intersection(match2_set))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I unfortunately, wasnt specific enough on the requirement of keeping list order. I have added an EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply remove the duplicates using:

```
print(list(dict.fromkeys(list(common)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension and then run that through `set()`

```
match1 = ['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'notcomplete' , 'next']
match2 = ['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'blocked', 'paper' , 'next']
print(set([x for x in match1 if x in match2]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to keep the order of the list and that's why I used __ 
 contains __ . I have added an EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Krishnadas welcome to StackOverflow,

You can convert the lists into sets which are data structures that don't allow duplicates in them. I see that you've used it on `match1` but you can also use them on `match2`:

```
common = filter(set(match1).__contains__,set(match2))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to keep the order of the list and that's why I used __ 
 contains __ . I have added an EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find an answer for this.

`match1 = ['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'notcomplete' , 'next']`

`match2 = ['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'blocked', 'paper' , 'next']`

`common = list(filter(match1.__contains__,match2))`

`common_final = [w for w in match1 if w in common]`

`print(common_final)`

Gives

`['Submit' , 'paper' , 'error' , 'code' , 'next']`

Thank you to everyone who helped.